# Render ReactJS app on demand by calling a JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am wondering if it's possible to initialize react app in same way as a for example a jQuery component, since we need to create some widget with some options that would be so much easier in react than in pure JS/jQuery.

I have tried to wrap `render(...)` in a `window.MyInitFunction = function ({....}) {render(<App />}` then calling it in html, but it's undefined.

My goal is for example calling function

```
MyInitFunction({'selector': '.foo', 'someOtherProp': 'bar'});
```

and it will render the react app in the given selector which might be one or multiple elements.

I guess that there might be few problems if rendered to multiple elements since it will use the same js code for storing for example redux state,...

Goal is also to create a jQuery compatible extension from it in form of: `$(".foo").MyInitFunction({.....});`

Tried to google it, but nearly all results are irrelevant to what I want to achieve, mostly dynamically loading components, which is not my case.

```
$(".foo").MyInitFunction({.....});
```

Thank you in advance for any tips :)

Comment: checkout web components https://reactjs.org/docs/web-components.html

Comment: i have tried it again what I did before and now it works, no idea what I did wrong, but now the function is not undefined and it's fully callable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to `render` a React app conditionally when you want. Check the snippet below. It renders the react app on click of the button.

```js
// React Component
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello from React!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

function renderReactApp() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
}

function init() {
  document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", function() {
    renderReactApp();
  });
}

init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <button id="start">render react app from outside</button>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I need, I can do that too. Although I appreciate the effort. The react code should be ES6 code, compiled by webpack/react-scripts which will generate a single bundle. Than this bundle is included in the html code and by calling "renderReactApp();" function anywhere in the html or in a separate JS file that is not part of the react project bundle. If you ever used for example any jQuery plugins for example selectize, matchHeight, slick... they come as a minified single file script which initialize with a single function.

Comment: I have tried it again, with same approach i tried before and now it works and it's not undefined, I have no idea

Comment: @ErikKubica haha, good for you! we have all been there before :)